# Associating file with data point?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, hyperlink

Is it possible with GRASS or QGIS to link a data point on a map with a report of some kind (photo, pdf, graph etc)?

I am interested in this feature, to facilitate data entry from the field, understanding of site conditions, tracking data, presentation etc.

Comment: Please decide which of the GIS products mentioned you want to ask about in this particular question.  By asking about more than one you are effectively asking multiple questions which goes against the [Tour].  You can always ask about the other product in a separate question.

Comment: Have you tried searching the help of those products for "hyperlink"?